# jstree on jQuery dialog on vertical scroll bar gives X icon with text of all jstree data

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog, jstree

I have a jQuery dialog and on top of that there is jstree. When i do vertical scroll bar it shows text of all tree items with mouse icon.

My jstree plugins does not have dnd and it is initialized like this:

```
plugins: ['themes', 'json_data', 'crrm', 'checkbox'],
```

[image]

After Dialog opens and when I click on scroll it shows red cross icon along with mouse with text of all options. This dialog is initialized like this:

```
 modal = $('<div></div>').addClass(this.widgetBaseClass + '-modal').dialog({
            modal: true,
            width: 500,
            autoOpen: false,
            resizable: false,               
            position: 'center',
            buttons: [{
                text: 'Save',
                click: $.proxy(this._save, this)
            }, {
                text: 'Cancel',
                click: $.proxy(this._cancel, this)
            }],
            title: 'Select ' + this.options.label
        });
```

This is happening with (IE9, FF, Chrome) Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my own question pretty soon after asking about it (typical) :)

**I tried couple of things but one of the solution is to set `draggable : false` to dialog is fixing it.**

I think this might be useful to someone who is facing similar issue. If you think it is not then please feel free to delete it. (I am not able to delete it).